# How to calculate $I^{'}\left(0\right)=2\sqrt{2}$, $I\left(x\right)=\intop_{0}^{2x}f\left(x-t\right)dt$,

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

How to calculate $I^{'}\left(0\right)$, $I\left(x\right)=\intop_{0}^{2x}f\left(x-t\right)dt$,
where
\begin{equation}
f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}x+x^{2}\right)}{x} & x\ne0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I did $y=x-t$, then $I\left(x\right)$ becomes $I\left(x\right)=\intop_{-x}^{x}f\left(y\right)dy$.
Then I am not sure how to continue.

Then I am not sure how to continue.

The derivative $I'(x)$ at $x=0$ should be calculated by the definition?

Any hint? Thank you very much

Comment: Use the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: the derivative should be calculated differently ?

Comment: The problem is that $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Here you can a) replace $f$ with a continuous version (redefine $f(0)$ as $\sqrt{2}$), or use $I'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} I'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Leibnitz theorem to differentiate the integral
thus $$I'(x)=f(x-2x)\cdot2-f(x-0)\cdot0=2f(-x)$$

$$ I'\left(x\right)=
2\frac{\ln\left(1-\sqrt{2}x+x^{2}\right)}{-x} , x\ne0 $$

$$I'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\ln\left(1-\sqrt{2}x+x^{2}\right)}{-x}$$

use LHopital's rule to calculate the limit thus $I'(0)=2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: the derivative at zero is correct ?

Comment: ok I have edited it you need to calculate the limit

Comment: Yes. When I did change of variable $y=x-t$, why it did not work?

Comment: Since the integrand depends on $x$, the Leibniz rule includes a differentiation under the integral (some care must be taken since $f$ as defined isn't continuous at $0$, but that can be dealt with). It's easier however to first substitute as @Lithium suggested.

Comment: Even using the Leibnitz theorem, did you miss the one term ?

Comment: I got $I\left(x\right)=\intop_{-x}^{x}f\left(y\right)dy$. Then what should I do ? @Daniel Fischer

Comment: @Lithium Since $f$ is continuous at $x\neq 0$, the FTC yields $I'(x) = f(x) - f(-x)\cdot (-1) = f(x) + f(-x)$ for $x\neq 0$. Thus $I'(0) = 2\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: OH I see, right right. And if using the Leibnitz theorem, there are three terms, why one term was missed? @Daniel Fischer